# change color of disabled drop down text with vuejs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2

What I'm looking for is when I select an item I want the option to be disabled in the dropdown list.  The following code is working as I expect, but the color of the disabled text is too light.  I would like to make it darker or even use a bootstrap color class(primary,secondary).

Is there a way to change the color of the disabled text in the vuejs code or do I have make the change in the CSS?

**HTML/vuejs:**

```
<option v-for="chores in chores.Data" :key="chores.ChoreId" v-bind:value="chores.ChoreId" :disabled="dailyChoreCheck(chores.ChoreId)">{{chores.ChoreName}}</option>
```

**Function:**

```
  dailyChoreCheck: function(selectedChoreId){
        var vm = this;
        if(vm.customChores.length > 0){
            return vm.customChores.filter(function(item) {
                return  item.choreId == selectedChoreId && item.dayName == "Daily";
            }).length > 0;
        }
  }
```

Comment: Are you using the Vue SFC for the particular component? If so, just the scoped css in `<style>` for you to achieve this.

Comment: @RuChernChong - No I'm not.  Can you supply the link to that?  I've never heard of that.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

css is required to style the disabled text. You can either style the disabled option elements through:

```
option:disabled {
   color: #abcdef;
}
```

or use Vue's [dynamic class](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) to add custom classes to those disabled options and then use css on them.

For me the former approach is simpler.

Comment: This is correct. The ideal way is to put this into the scoped style of the particular component.

Comment: @MarkFeng - The dynamic class stuff seems really cool.  I can capture a property that states it is disabled (setting it my check), but I can't seem to toggle the class for the disabled options.  Just the undisabled ones.  Any idea on how to target just the disabled options?

Comment: @webdad3 check my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/Mark_f/fvmyx7za/. As far as I know css doesn't work on the option of a native select element, but dynamic classes can be added. You can check the option elements in web inspecter and see the disabled options can be targeted.